# How do I access a JSON-property of a JSON-Object in php?

Tags: php, json

I've got a really weird problem and I can't figure out why. 
The situation is quite simple. My Android app uploads JSON data to a php script on my server. Right now I am trying to parse the data.

This is the JSON-Array passed to the script (via httpPost.setEntity ()):

> [{"friends_with_accepted":"false","friends_with_synced":"false","friends_with_second_id":"5","friends_with_first_id":"6"}]

This is the php script:

```
<?php
// array for JSON response
$response = array();

$json = file_get_contents ('php://input');
$jsonArray = json_decode ($json, true);
foreach ($jsonArray as $jsonObject) {
    $firstId   = $jsonObject['friends_with_first_id'];
    $accepted = $jsonObject ['friends_with_accepted'];
    $secondId = $jsonObject ['friends_with_second_id'];
    $synced   = $jsonObject ['friends_with_synced'];

    echo "accepted: ".$accepted."synced: ".$synced;
} ?>
```

And this is the response I get from the script:

> accepted: synced: false

**Why is the "synced" property correctly passed, but not the "accepted" property??**
I can't see the difference. Btw, firstId and secondId are parsed correctly as well.

Comment: Looks strange - have you done a `var_dump` of `$accepted` and `$synced` to compare?

Comment: yes, i compared them, var_dump($accepted,$synced) gave me the result:
NULL
string(5) "false"

Comment: Looks fine: http://codepad.org/JmvUmwBe

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i just found the problem:

Instead of

```
$accepted = $jsonObject ['friends_with_accepted'];
```

I deleted the space between jsonObject and the bracket

```
$accepted = $jsonObject['friends_with_accepted'];
```